# POST request for multiple database tables

Tags: database, postgresql, rest, post, api-design

I have two tables `component`, and `component_type_text`. Now, I have a POST request `/components/text`, which would insert a new record into the `component_type_text` table. The problem is, that `components` is the overcategory table for each specific component type. So this table would hold the `component_id`, `type`, and some other columns/attributes that are common across components.

So obviously, when performing this POST request, I would also somehow need to insert a record into the `component` table, as this is the "parent". And it is also used for other endpoints, for example DELETE `/components/{id}`.

What I thought about doing is, keeping the post requests as is `/components/text`, `/components/button`, and so on and then set up a trigger on the PostgreSQL database which inserts records into the `components` database once an insert happened on any `components_type_*` table.

Now the problem is that with this solution, I could not let the user pass custom attributes to the parent `component` table, which are the same across all the `component_type_*` tables. An example would be `custom_styles`, which every component could have.

I could have the `custom_styles` attribute defined in each different type table, but that would be against the rules of normalisation in SQL and not ideal.

Does anyone have an idea how I should handle this database/api design?